# React State / DOM Not Updating When All Items Deleted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I'm building an app with React and Firebase Realtime Database. Objects are added to an array and sent to the database.
The arrays are updated in React and the result is sent to the database.

The functionality to remove items/objects from the list works fine when there are more than one (i.e. button clicked, database, DOM and state updated immediately).

However, whenever there's one item left and you click its delete button, it's deleted from the database but the state and React DOM aren't updated - you have to refresh the page for it to be removed.

I've tried using different methods to update the database in case it triggered a different response but that didn't work - any ideas would be greatly appreciated:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Exercise from "./Exercise";
import AddNewWorkout from "./AddNewWorkout";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import WorkoutComponent from './WorkoutComponent';
import AddNewExercise from "./AddNewExercise"
import { database, set, ref, onValue, update } from "../firebase"

const Dashboard = ({user}) => {
    const [selectedWorkout, setSelectedWorkout] = useState();
    const [workouts, setWorkouts] = useState([])
    const [creatingNewWorkout, setCreatingNewWorkout] = useState(false);
    const [addingNewExercise, setAddingNewExercise] = useState(false)

function selectWorkout(number) {
    const selection = [...workouts].filter(workout => number == workout.id);
    setSelectedWorkout(selection[0])
}

function toggleNewWorkoutStatus(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    setCreatingNewWorkout(creatingNewWorkout => !creatingNewWorkout)
}

function toggleNewExerciseStatus() {
    setAddingNewExercise(addingNewExercise => !addingNewExercise)
}

function writeData() {
    const newWorkouts = [...workouts]
    const workoutTitle = document.getElementById("workoutTitle").value || new Date(Date.now()).toString()
    const workoutDate = document.getElementById("workoutDate").value;
    newWorkouts.push({
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: workoutTitle,
        date: workoutDate,
        exercises: []
    })

    set(ref(database, `${user.uid}/workouts/`), newWorkouts )
 
}

function addWorkoutToListDB(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    writeData(user.uid)
}

function removeWorkoutFromList(id) {
    const newWorkouts = [...workouts].filter(workout => id !== workout.id);
    update(ref(database, `${user.uid}`), {"workouts": newWorkouts} )

}

function addExerciseToWorkout(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (selectedWorkout === undefined) {
        alert("No workout selected") 
        return
    }

    const newWorkouts = [...workouts]
   const exerciseID = uuidv4();
    const exerciseName = document.getElementById("exerciseName").value
    const exerciseSets = document.getElementById("exerciseSets").value
    const exerciseReps = document.getElementById("exerciseReps").value
    const exerciseWeight = document.getElementById("exerciseWeight").value
    const exercisetTarget = document.getElementById("exercisetTarget").checked
    const exerciseNotes = document.getElementById("exerciseNotes").value;

    const newExercise = {
        id: exerciseID,
        name: exerciseName,
        sets: exerciseSets,
        reps: exerciseReps,
        weight: `${exerciseWeight}kg`,
        target: exercisetTarget,
        notes: exerciseNotes,
    }

    for (let key of newWorkouts) {
        if (key.id === selectedWorkout.id) {
            if (key.exercises) {
                key.exercises.push(newExercise)
            } else {
                key.exercises = [newExercise]
            }
        }

    }

    update(ref(database, `${user.uid}`), {"workouts": newWorkouts} )


}

function removeExerciseFromWorkout(id) {
    const newWorkouts = [...workouts];
    for (let workout of newWorkouts) {
        if(selectedWorkout.id === workout.id) {
            if (!workout.exercises) {return}
            workout.exercises = workout.exercises.filter(exercise => exercise.id !== id)
        }
    }

    const newSelectedWorkout = {...selectedWorkout}
    newSelectedWorkout.exercises = newSelectedWorkout.exercises.filter(exercise => exercise.id !== id)
    setSelectedWorkout(newSelectedWorkout)

    update(ref(database, `${user.uid}`), {"workouts": newWorkouts} )


}

useEffect(() => {

    function getWorkoutData() {
        const dbRef = ref(database, `${user.uid}`);
        onValue(dbRef, snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.val()) {
                console.log(snapshot.val().workouts)
                setWorkouts(workouts => workouts = snapshot.val().workouts)


            }

            
        }
            )
    }

    getWorkoutData()

},[])


  return (
    <div>
        {creatingNewWorkout && <AddNewWorkout addWorkoutToListDB={addWorkoutToListDB} toggleNewWorkoutStatus={toggleNewWorkoutStatus} /> }
        <div id="workoutDiv">
            <h2>Workouts</h2><p>{selectedWorkout ? selectedWorkout.title : "No workout selected"}</p>
            <Button type="button" onClick={toggleNewWorkoutStatus} className="btn btn-primary">Add New Workout</Button>
            {workouts && workouts.map(workout => <WorkoutComponent key={workout.id} removeWorkoutFromList={removeWorkoutFromList} selectWorkout={selectWorkout} workout={workout}/> )}
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Exercise</h2>
            {addingNewExercise && <AddNewExercise selectedWorkout={selectedWorkout} addExerciseToWorkout={addExerciseToWorkout} toggleNewExerciseStatus={toggleNewExerciseStatus}/> }
            <Button type="button" onClick={toggleNewExerciseStatus} className="btn btn-primary">Add New Exercise</Button>


            {selectedWorkout && selectedWorkout.exercises && selectedWorkout.exercises.map(exercise => <Exercise removeExerciseFromWorkout={removeExerciseFromWorkout} key={exercise.id} exercise={exercise}/>)}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

If it helps, the data flow I'm working to is:

1. New array copied from state
2. New array updated as necessary
3. New array sent to database
4. Database listener triggers download of new array
5. New array saved to state

I have tried to use different methods (set, update and remove) in case that triggered the onValue function.

I have also tried to send null values and deleting empty nodes if the array that will be sent to the db is empty.

The above methods didn't have any impact, there was still a problem with the last array element that was only resolved by refreshing the browser.

I have tried to remove the array dependency and add the workout state as a dependency, resulting in the following error: "Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render."

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand where the issue was:

In the useEffect call, I set up the state to only be updated if the value in returned from the database was null (to prevent an error I ran into). However, this meant that state wasn't being updated at all when I deleted the last item from the array.

I appear to have fixed this by adding an else clause.

``````
useEffect(() => {

    function getWorkoutData() {
        const dbRef = ref(database, `${user.uid}`);
        onValue(dbRef, snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.val()) {
                console.log(snapshot.val().workouts)
                setWorkouts(workouts => workouts = snapshot.val().workouts)
            } else {
                setWorkouts(workouts => workouts = [])
            }

            
        }
            )
    }

    getWorkoutData()

},[])

`````
``````